# dpkg-checkbuilddeps fail to recognize installed packages

Tags: package-management, compiling, deb

I'm trying to build a package which depends (*build depends*) on several other packages. For some reason `dpkg-checkbuilddeps` shows some dependencies as if they were not installed, while in practice, they are:

```
> dpkg-checkbuilddeps
dpkg-checkbuilddeps: Unmet build dependencies: zlib1g-dev python
> dpkg -l zlib1g-dev python
.
.
.||/ Name                                      Version                   Architecture              Description

+++-=========================================-=========================-=========================-===============================
ii  python                                    2.7.8-3                   i386                      interactive high-level object-oriented language (default version)
ii  zlib1g-dev:i386                           1:1.2.8.dfsg-2+b1         i386                      compression library - development
```

Note that both zlib1g-dev are specified in `debian/control` **without** a version restriction.

What goes wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason for the discrepancy is that the installed packages for zlib1g-dev and python are of the i386 architecture, while your base system is something else; probably amd64 (aka x86_64). Unless your build dependencies are explicitly marked as being satisfiable by a package from a different architecture, those packages you have installed wouldn't count.

The ability to install packages from multiple architectures simultaneously on the same host is a relatively new one in the Ubuntu/Debian world, which may have contributed to your confusion. If it helps, you might want to read through https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiArch.